# Using OpenMP with llvm-clang

Tags: c, openmp, llvm-clang

So I tried to use OpenMP with one of the latest version of clang, `clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)`. Followed the procedure to compile and add the PATHs of `omp.h`, then Compiling my hello.c using :

```
clang -fopenmp hello.c
```

and then running it, still it can't use more than 1 threads:

```
Bash-4.1$ ./a.out 
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 1
```

P.S: I tried to manually export `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` but that didn't solve anything as well. Any ideas?

UPDATE: This is the hello.c:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for `hello.c`.

Comment: here it is @Mysticial

Comment: Why not try #pragma omp parallel num_threads(#noofthreads)

Comment: @TejasPatel, i already tried that but didn't work. the same `Hello from thread 0, nthreads 1` apears

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the fact that its kinda late regarding the time-stamp of my original question, but I would like to mention the answer here so at-least it saves people's time facing similar issue.

LLVM itself currently doesn't support `Openmp` right out-of-the-box. You can make it compile and run the `omp` tagged code with [Intel Runtime Support](http://openmp.llvm.org/). However, if you want to have a clean `clang` supporting OpenMP, there is a trunk of the project at [OpenMP-Clang](https://clang-omp.github.io/) which you can clone and build. The current support is OpenMP 3.1 specification and they will reach to support OpenMP 4.0 specification soon:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/llvm_trunk llvm
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/compiler-rt_trunk llvm/projects/compiler-rt
$ git clone https://github.com/clang-omp/clang_trunk llvm/tools/clang
```

Don't forget to build the  `Intel® OpenMP* Runtime Library` after this as you need `omp.h` and `/path/to/llvm/projects/openmp/runtime/lin_32e/lib/libomp.so`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting number of threads using omp_set_num_thread() function. If it doesn't work, try setting up clang again.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
      omp_set_num_threads(4);
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
      printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),       omp_get_num_threads());
      }    
}
```

Also try calling mp_get_max_threads() in both parallel and serial region, and see what you get

Comment: interesting thing is when I execute this : `clang -g -emit-llvm -S -c -fopenmp hello.c -o hello.ll` i am getting this warning: `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'`, do you know why ??

Comment: If you don't use -fopenmp, does compiler throw error about undefined reference to functions of openMP. If not the library might be included by default

Comment: no I have carried out the procedures here : `http://openmp.llvm.org/` and install the library and exported the path. before that I had error but now not anymore.

Comment: so if you don't use -fopenmp, it compiles succesfully?

Comment: yes. wait a moment. did I have to download a new version of clang to use with opennmp? i used my current clang one

Comment: try downloading new one.btw what does omp_get_max_threads() give in parallel region

Comment: yes, i forgot. it manually set the max to 4 : `Hello from thread 0, nthreads 1, maxThreads is 4`

Comment: strange behaviour. sorry i have no further idea about it. maybe u should have better chance on openmp forum

Comment: cheers buddy ;) let me try this other clang version and report this.

Answer (score 0):

I was only seeing one thread too, with clang version 3.8.0 (trunk 252425). I then read some recent news at https://clang-omp.github.io:

> November 27, 2015 - Further development of OpenMP support in
>   clang/llvm compiler moved to www.llvm.org. This site is maintained for
>   archival purposes only. Thank you to everyone who contributed all
>   these years!

...and so I compiled LLVM/Clang from trunk; compiled the OpenMP runtime library using the excellent instructions [here](http://openmp.llvm.org); and now it does work.